# Packer: What's difference between attaching scripts as floppies and including them in provisioner scripts?

Tags: packer

I can see in many templates of packer that, some files are attached as floppies, so that these are executed right when the VM creation completes in a builder, and some files are included in provisioner scripts so that they are executed serially later.

What's difference between the two? How to decide which script to include in floppies and which file to include in provioner scripts?

Answer (score 1):

As per https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/vmware-vmx.html#floppy_files the floppy is useful for unattended installation. The floppy will contain files required for the same.

Whereas the provisioner will contain files that are required for configuring the system after it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Some operating systems no longer support the floppy images, but those that do typically use it for bootstrapping via kickstart or a Debian installer preseed. Many bootstrap methods support using a web server to host these files as well, so Packer provides a built in webserver to provide this functionality for building boxes if they don't have floppy support or the files are too large to fit on a 1.44M disk.